# Dynamic Linq 2 Sql using Expressions Trees raising exception "Binary Operator LessThan not defined for System.String and System.String"

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, expression-trees

I'm trying to write a dynamic Linq 2 Sql query using Expressions trees but I'm getting a exception telling me that the LessThan and GreaterThan operators are not defined for `System.String` and `System.String`, which i find odd, is that true? or am I doing something wrong?

```
Expression<Func<SomeDataContextType, string>> codeSelectorExpresion = 
    x => x.CodeColumn;
var row = Expression.Parameter(typeof(SomeDataContextType), "row");
var expression = 
   Expression.GreaterThan(
       Expression.Invoke(codeSelectorExpression, row),
       Expression.Constant("someString", typeof(string)));
//I'm trying to build something like SomeDataContextType.CodeColumn > "someString"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, after strugling for a while i realized that the `>` and `<` operators on strings are implemented calling to `string.CompareTo`, so i updated the code to use the `string.CompareTo` method instead and it worked. Thank you anyway,
Tthe expression need to be:

```
var expression =
    Expression.GreaterThan(
       Expression.Call(
            Expression.Invoke(codeSelectorExpression, row), 
            typeof(string).GetMethod("CompareTo", new[] {typeof(string)}),
            Expression.Constant("someString")),
       Expression.Constant(0, typeof(int)));
```