# Entity framework string datatype using >,>=,<,<= operator : Lambda expression

Tags: c#-4.0, lambda

I am working on a dynamic Lambda expression query, without using an API.

If the user selects the FieldName as "AddressLine1" and Operator as >=  FieldValue as "K"
It should return the results as All the AddressLine1 Field values which starts with K and L,M till Z series.

Here is the code, it works for integer datatypes:

```
public static Expression CreateBinaryExpression(Expression argLeft, Expression argRight, operatorType opType) {
    switch ((operatorType)opType) {    
        case operatorType.Greater:
            return Expression.GreaterThan(argLeft, argRight);
        case operatorType.GreaterEqual:
            return Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(argLeft, argRight);
        ...
    }
}
```

How to modify the code to work with String datatype for Greater than Equal operator. I am looking for expression for this. Anybody have ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`String.Compare()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84787k22.aspx) method:

```
return String.Compare(argLeft, argRight) >= 0;
```

`Compare()` returns <0 if strA is less than strB, 0 when they are equal, and >0 if strA is greater than strB.

Comment: Knittl,                                                       return String.Compare(argLeft, argRight) > 0;                       return String.Compare(argLeft, argRight) >= 0;
Both are returning same results. Do you have any idea? regarding this I posted here                                          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390695/lambda-expression-compare-operator-issue

Answer (score 1):

got the solution from here

[Dynamic Linq 2 Sql using Expressions Trees raising exception "Binary Operator LessThan not defined for System.String and System.String"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061398/dynamic-linq-2-sql-using-expressions-trees-raising-exception-binary-operator-le)

switch ((operatorType)opType)
    {

```
 case operatorType.Greater: return Expression.GreaterThan(
                            Expression.Call(typeof(string),
                            "Compare", null, new[] { argLeft, argRight }),
                             Expression.Constant(0, typeof(int)));

}
```