# Lambda expression Compare operator ">",">=" issue

Tags: c#, lambda

when I execute these operators( `>` and `>=`) lambda expression in entity framework. both are getting same results.

1. `db.Companies.where(Company => (Compare(Convert(Company.Name), "y") > 0))`
2. `db.Companies.where(Company => (Compare(Convert(Company.Name), "y") >= 0))`

Is that issue with Lambda expression compare operator? 
i changed to

1. `db.Companies.where(Company => (Compare(Convert(Company.Name), "y") > 1))` - No results. Its **not correct**
2. `db.Companies.where(Company => (Compare(Convert(Company.Name), "y") >= 1))` - 64 results

**source code**

```
case operatorType.Greater: return Expression.GreaterThan(Expression.Call(typeof(string),
                            "Compare", null, new[] { argLeft, argRight }),
                             Expression.Constant(1, typeof(int)));

case operatorType.GreaterEqual: return Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(       Expression.Call(typeof(string), "Compare", null, new[]  { argLeft, argRight }),
                        Expression.Constant(1, typeof(int)));
```

Comment: What are `Convert` and `Compare`?

Comment: Well, without seeing them, we can't tell what they are supposed to evaluate to.

Comment: -1 incomplete question!what do Convert and Compare `do`..

Comment: Convert I used for the typecast with FieldType.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all responses The Lambda expression query is correct only.

```
db.Companies.where(Company => (Compare(Convert(Company.Name), "Test") > 0))
db.Companies.where(Company => (Compare(Convert(Company.Name), "Test") >= 0))
```

I changed the "right arg" value to "Test". I have one record 'Name' with Test. executed the following query.

```
db.Companies.where(Company => (Compare(Convert(Company.Name), "Test") > 0))
```

and shown the results 105(here Name with 'Test' is not shown.  - **Correct**

Then I executed this

```
db.Companies.where(Company => (Compare(Convert(Company.Name), "Test") >= 0))
```

and shown the results 106(here Name with 'Test' is shown) - **Correct**

Answer (score 2):

If you're gettnig the same results, means that there is no `Company.Name` equal to "Y"

Comment: db.Companies.where(Company => (Compare(Convert(Company.Name), "y") > 0)) gave 64   results.                               db.Companies.where(Company => (Compare(Convert(Company.Name), "y") >= 0)) too gave 64 results

Comment: you should show us what does Comapare/Convert do. But if Compare works the same as String.Compare, if the result is > 0 means that the company names are different to "Y". So, your where is returning all your names different to "Y"

Comment: string.compare will return something greater than zero if the first operand is greater than the second.  It will be non-zero of the two are unequal.

Comment: OF course. So, if you use > 0, will return anything that is greater than 0. And if you use >= 0, you will get anything that is zero or greater. So, if you are getting the same results, that means that there isn't a 0, so there isn't a Company.Name equals to "Y" (your comparison)

Comment: @ElVieejo Yes.  Your answer text is correct (assuming `Compare` and `Convert` do what you think they do) but your comment is not.  `"if the result is > 0 means that the company names are different to "Y". So, your where is returning all your names different to "Y""`.  All company names different from 'y' would be `(Compare(Convert(Company.Name), "y") != 0)`.

Comment: > 0 implies != 0. If there's no 0 value returned, >=0 also implies != 0. And well, if your Compare  don't do the same that String.Compare, then post your code, if not where are just guessing..

Answer (score 0):

Why would you expect the answer to be different.

- What does `Compare` do?
- What does `Convert` do?
- What does `Compare(Convert(Company.Name), "y")` evaluate to?

If it evaluates to `1` or greater then both answers would be correct.

Comment: both "would be true", not "would be correct"  Since we don't know the requirements we have no idea what "correct" should be.  Also they could both result in anything less than 0 and be the same.  They will only differ if compare sometimes returns 0.

Comment: Well I say this because looking at the code, and with a few assumptions about what the unshown methods do, my guess is neither is correct.  He probably should be using `!=` rather than either greater than or greater than or equal.

Comment: I tried this                                      db.Companies.where(Company => (Compare(Convert(Company.Name), "y") > 1)) - No results
db.Companies.where(Company => (Compare(Convert(Company.Name), "y") >= 1)) -64 results --my query expressions code for greaterthanEqual :                                                                case operatorType.GreaterEqual: return Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(Expression.Call(typeof(string),"Compare", null, new[] { argLeft, argRight }),            Expression.Constant(1, typeof(int)));

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same number of results for both queries then it means that `(Compare(Convert(Company.Name), "y")` is never equal to zero.  If it is anything greater than zero both queries will return it; if it's anything less than zero then neither query will return it.